# sensors in C# on windows8 desktop application

Tags: c#, windows-8, sensors

I am trying to write a simple application in c# on windows8 desktop application that will display accelerometer changes.
I am using windows7.SensorsAndLocation dll and write the following code.

```
private static Accelerometer3D _accelerometer3D;

    private static Accelerometer3DReport _accelerometer3DReport;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sensor[] accelerometers = SensorManager.GetSensorsByType(SensorTypes.Accelerometer3d);

        if (accelerometers.Length > 0)
        {
            _accelerometer3D = (Accelerometer3D)accelerometers[0];
            _accelerometer3D.DataUpdated += _accelerometer3D_DataUpdated;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void _accelerometer3D_DataUpdated(Sensor sensor, SensorDataReport dataReport)
    {
        _accelerometer3DReport = dataReport as Accelerometer3DReport;
         float f = _accelerometer3DReport.AxisX_G;
    }
```

when I run this code and data has updated, it runs into the _accelerometer3D_DataUpdated function, but then it crached on this line:

```
float f = _accelerometer3DReport.AxisX_G;
```

with system.invalidcastexception: Specified cast is not valid.
I don't see any other details.

when I run the same code with ambientLightSensors it works fine.

any suggestions?

please HELP!!!
NOTE: I am using desktop application so I can't use windows8 sensors API.
and, ofcourse, I have accelerometer on my device (Microsoft surface pro x64);

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the source for the library you're using is the [Sensor and Location Sample Interop library](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/04/02/windows-7-sensor-and-location-net-interop-sample-library.aspx).  In the code there, you'll note:

```
    public float AxisX_G
    {
        get { return (float)this.GetDataField(PropertyKey.Create(new Guid(0X3F8A69A2, 0X7C5, 0X4E48, 0XA9, 0X65, 0XCD, 0X79, 0X7A, 0XAB, 0X56, 0XD5), 2)); }
    }
```

so I suspect the float cast is causing the exception implying that `GetDataField` isn't returning what was expected.  You might pull in that code and set a breakpoint to see what is coming back

There's a [Sensor Diagnostic Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh780319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that's part of the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) and I wonder if that will be able to read the value correctly?